# EasyAdminBundle how to add another key/value to referer url

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Anyone on how I can set a key/value pairs in the URL to maintain state?

[image]

Basically I would like to keep state in the list page based on the checkbox. If I edit a row and come back to this page, I would like the list to remain the same as it was. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your list.html.twig. for ex. Hide checkbox id is hide_archived.

```
{% if app.request.query.has('hide_archived') %}
    {% set _request_parameters = ({ hide_archived: app.request.get('hide_archived') }) %}
{% endif %}
```